# Wordpress pages error

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

[image: title error]

when i create new pages title comes out like that and also in the WPbakery and I use the design option to design any elements on the page it doesn't show up

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related, so likely belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are adding `<mark>` tag in wordpress, not an issue. In screenshot there are 3 titles and two of them have mark tag only, can you please check the title tag inside of editing screen ?

I hope that is coming from title itself.